# Image maps not working in any browser

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, firefox, imagemap

I can't seem to get the image map to work correctly, I have no idea what's wrong. Can someone help?

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/PJqtHll.jpg" width="742" height="798" border="0" alt="image" usemap="#Map" /> <map id="Map" name="Map">
<area shape="poly" coords="57,462,198,761" href="http://www.avery.ca/avery/en_ca/Products/Labels/Mailing-Labels/2up-White-Laser-Shipping-Labels_05126.htm" />
<area shape="poly" coords="222,462,363,762" href="http://www.avery.ca/avery/en_ca/Products/Labels/Mailing-Labels/LBL-LRS-4X2-PERM-WE_05163.htm" />
<area shape="poly" coords="382,460,522,766" href="http://www.avery.ca/avery/en_ca/Products/Labels/Mailing-Labels/Lbl-Lsr-4X-3_1-3-Perm-White_05164.htm" />
<area shape="poly" coords="540,458,687,763" href="http://www.avery.ca/avery/en_ca/Products/Labels/Mailing-Labels/LBL-LSR-WE-SHIP-5X3_.5-100SHT_05168.htm" />
<area shape="poly" coords="600,346,692,384" href="http://www.avery.ca/avery/en_ca/Help-Centre/Quick-Help/Avery-Design-and-Print-Online/How-to-Mail-Merge-using-Avery-Design--Print-Online.htm" />
<area shape="rect" coords="599,165,689,205" href="http://www.avery.ca/avery/en_ca/Project-%26-Ideas/Ideas-for-Work/Mailing/Articles/Think-Outside-the-Box.htm" />
<area shape="poly" coords="32,324,173,379" href="http://www.avery.ca/print" />
</map></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're specifying polygons with only 2 points, which would result in no area to click...
I would expect the rectangle to work though, since you specify 2 points for that one.
What happens if you change them all to rect or add additional points to the polygons?

Comment: Works! Such a dumb mistake on my end. Thank you :)